# I want my app.db to be automatically created inside a package folder, every time I command migrate

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

this is my directory

```
hotel/
___grandluis/
______main/
______static/
______templates/
______users/
______config.py
______models.py
___migrations/
______versions/
___run.py
___app.db
```

My problem is I want my app.db to be inside of `grandluis` folder. because every time I run `python run.py db migrate`. my app.db gets created outside of `grandluis` folder and when I add something to my database through my app it creates another app.db inside the `grandluis` folder. I'ts like my flask app only reads the app.db which is inside the `grandluis` folder not the one which is outside of `grandluis` folder. Because It can cause an error. It says that there's no `SQLAlchemy.model` that has been created. Because my app only read the app.db which is inside of `grandluis`. So I want that every time I command migrate, I want that it will create/affect the app.db which is inside my `grandluis` folder. I really want some Answers guys Thank you so much for having time to read this ridiculous question of mine.

--models.py--

```
from datetime import datetime
from itsdangerous import TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer as Serializer
from flask import current_app
from grandluis import db, loginManager
from flask_login import UserMixin

@loginManager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    UserId = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(300), nullable=False)
    address = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    contact = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)

class Room(db.Model):
    roomId = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    roomNum = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    roomType = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    roomPrice = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    roomStatus = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
class Meals(db.Model):
    mealId = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    mealName = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    mealType = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    mealPrice = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    mealStatus = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

class Service(db.Model):
    serId = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    serName = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    serPrice = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    serStatus = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

class Guest(db.Model, UserMixin):
    GuestId = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstName = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    lastName = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    middleName = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    address = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    #posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)

    def get_reset_token(self, expires_sec=1800):
        s = Serializer(current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'], expires_sec)
        return s.dumps({'guest_id': self.id}).decode('utf-8')

    @staticmethod
    def verify_reset_token(token):
        s = Serializer(current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        try:
            user_id = s.loads(token)['guest_id']
        except:
            return None
        return Guest.query.get(user_id)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Guest('{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.image_file}')"
```

--config.py--

```
class Config:
    SECRET_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXX'
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///app.db'
    MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.googlemail.com'
    MAIL_PORT = 587
    MAIL_USE_TLS = True
    MAIL_USERNAME = 'xxxxxx@gmail.com'
    MAIL_PASSWORD = 'xxxxxx'
```

--run.py--

```
from grandluis import db, createApp
from flask_migrate import MigrateCommand
from flask_script import Manager

app = createApp()
manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

Comment: can you please give more details about your question, the code part that you have written to create database

Comment: I Edited it Sir.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the Config.py python file. You should specify the path for the database properly. Change your code like this:

First of all import os library to the config.py file.

```
import os
```

Then make a variable. In my case I name that variable as basedir:

```
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Now you can specify your path for the database. Change your SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI as follows:

```
 SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') or \
                                  'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'hotel\\grandluis\\app.db')
 SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
```

Go to your run.py python file and do these changes:

```
from grandluis import db, createApp
from flask_migrate import MigrateCommand
from flask_script import Manager
fro flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = createApp()
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

db.init_app(app)
db.app = app
db.create_all()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

Comment: It says "return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)"

Comment: Uhmm for further info. Im just using sqlite.